# BeautifulSoup: Get generic tags from a specific class only

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get all the text I want from an HTML file when I use beautifulsoup like this:

```
category = soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
catname = BeautifulSoup(str(category).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8")
```

Output:

```
Home
Digital Goods
E-Books
```

BUT I want to skip the first category, i.e. 'Home'. I know that I can simply replace that word with "", but my question is really about how I get get beautifulsoup to get a very specific tag *in the location I have singled out above*.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="http://fakeshop.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fakeshop.com/category/51">Digital Goods</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fakeshop.com/category/98">E-Books</a></li>
</ol>
```

Is there anything I can do to get the second and third 'li' tags from this 'breadcrumb' section, and not others in the file?

Example (which does not work but illustrates what I'm looking for):

```
category = soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"}), find_all("li")[1:]
```

Comment: Example `category = soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"}), find_all("li")[1:]` does not work ??? What output you get? This must be working

Comment: Thanks for the comment! No it doesn't work. I get this error: NameError: global name 'find_all' is not defined. When I change it to soup.find_all("li")[1:] I get ALL "li" tags, not just those within the particular section (class:breadcrumb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this:

```
category = soup.find("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"}).findAll('li')[1:]
catname = BeautifulSoup(str(category).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8")
```

?

My output is then:

```
[Digital Goods, E-Books]
```

Comment: But I don't know if this ordered list you have posted above is the first one since "find" finds only the first appearance.